How to copy SharePoint Lists and Libraries from one site to another site
How can I copy SharePoint list and library from the one site to another site?
For example:
Copy Lists and Libraries from
https://myCompany/sites/mySite1
to
https://myCompany/sites/mySite2
I don't want the data, I just want the structure/settings/columns without data.

How many lists/libraries you want to copy from one site to another?

Easiest way to copy SharePoint online list/library structure/settings/columns without data from SharePoint UI is --> use "From existing list/library" option while creating a new list or library.
Example - for list:

Go to your SharePoint site home page or site contents page

Select +New > List.

On the Create a list page, select From existing list.


Select the site that has the existing list, select the list and then Next.


Enter the name for the new list and select Create.


Microsoft documentation: Create a new SharePoint list based on the columns in another list.
Similar option is available for SharePoint document libraries as well:

Microsoft documentation: Create a document library in SharePoint.

Other available options:

Using PowerShell: Copy SharePoint list to another site - The script will copy the list settings, permissions, views and columns.
Using Site templates: SharePoint site template and site script overview.
Using 3rd party migration tools (licenses may needed) - Migration tools like ShareGate, Metalogix, AvePoint, etc.

